# Japan character encoding

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe

I have Japanese string of 'ぱはめ'. I want to convert it into '%82%CF%82%CD%82%DF'. I hope someone will give me a function for this converting.

Comment: What does your normal URL encoding function produce?

Comment: my function is a bit long. the space here is not enough to write my function. I don't know how to add long text in here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the string and encode it in a specific code page. Then take each encoded byte and produce its hex representation. Like this:

```
function MyEncode(const S: string; const CodePage: Integer): string;
var
  Encoding: TEncoding;
  Bytes: TBytes;
  b: Byte;
  sb: TStringBuilder;
begin
  Encoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(932);
  try
    Bytes := Encoding.GetBytes(S);
  finally
    Encoding.Free;
  end;

  sb := TStringBuilder.Create;
  try
    for b in Bytes do begin
      sb.Append('%');
      sb.Append(IntToHex(b, 2));
    end;
    Result := sb.ToString;
  finally
    sb.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Although you have not stated this, you wish to encode the text as code page 932. So you should pass that value when calling the function.

```
Writeln(MyEncode('ぱはめ', 932));
```

I must say that in the modern day, it is somewhat surprising to see this Windows specific multi byte encoding still in use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time in helping me. Now i can solve my problem. Thank again. :)